# Ford Escape 2009 - Engine Noisy above 3000rpm

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a 2009 Ford Escape with automatic transmission with 174,000 miles on the odometer.

When I accelerate to 100km/h I am at more than 3000 rpm and the engine is making a heavy noise. A friend recommended that I change the spark plugs, which I did but the problem remains. I do not know what to do.

J'ai une Ford Escape de 2009 transmission avec 174 000 mil au tableau automatique. lorsque j'accélère déjà a 100km/h je suis à plus de 3000 tour minutes et le moteur émet un bruit lourd.un copin ma recommandé de changer les bougies, ce que j'ai fais mais le problème demeure. je sais pas quoi faire.

Comment: @roilion1225 Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair SE! The site only accepts questions in English so I've done my best to translate your question.

Comment: Presumably the revs used to be lower at 60kmh?  Sounds like the auto box is not going into top gear.

Comment: Have you checked that the auto transmission fluid is at the correct level?